# Sharing the same card

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I choose 5 numbers from 1 to 12 randomly, and my friend does so as well. What is the probability that we share $n$ numbers? I know that the denominator will be $12 \choose 5$$12 \choose 5$ but I am having trouble deriving the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Your denominator looks all right. Let's define a *random variable* X such that X = "the number of shared numbers between 2 randomly chosen sets of the numbers 1-12." This helps us considerably when solving the problem: you are trying to solve for the Probability of X=n $\implies P(X=n)$.

Before continuing, it is worth seeing exactly what values X can take on. It is important to realize that $n$ can be at most 5 and that $n$ will be some non-negative integer. Can X=0? That would mean you could pick 1,2,3,4,5 and your friend would pick 6,7,8,9,10 for example, so yes this can happen. It is easy to see then that $n$ must take on a value from the set $\{0,1,  2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

A reasonable approach to this type of problem when learning probability is to calculate $P(X=n)$ for some values of $n$ and see if any pattern develops. Like you have reasoned, the total number of ways for both you and your friend to choose 5 numbers from a set of 12 is $$\binom{12}{5} \binom{12}{5} = {\binom{12}{5}}^2 = (792)^2 = 627264 \text{ ways}$$

The pattern might be easier to recognize if we start out with $P(X=1)$. We'll consider $P(X=0)$ later. Sharing one number with your friend means that you have 1 card out of 12 in common. The number of ways to do this (that is, pick a random number from 12 numbers) is $\binom{12}{1}$. You now have to pick 4 numbers to get a complete hand of 5 numbers, and there are still 11 numbers to choose from. This means you have $\binom{11}{4}$ ways to pick your numbers. What about your friend? He/she already has a number that you share (which is why $n=1$ here) so they need $5-1=4$ more numbers. But you have taken 5 of the 12 already, so your friend has $12-5=7$ numbers left to choose from. That is, picking 4 numbers from a set of 7 remaining numbers can be done in $\binom{7}{4}$ ways.

All together now, you need to multiply each binomial coefficient generated above, all divided by the total number of ways this scenario can occur, to get
$$ P(X=1) = \frac{\binom{12}{1} \binom{11}{4} \binom{7}{4}}{627264} = \frac{138600}{627264} \approx 0.221$$

Similarly, you can derive an expression for $P(X=2)$ by seeing that the shared number can be chosen in $\binom{12}{2}$ ways. You still need to pick $5-2=3$ numbers from the $12-2=10$ numbers remaining; this can be done in $\binom{10}{3}$ ways. Just like before, you friend already has 2 numbers chosen that match yours and they need to pick 3 numbers from the ones $12-5=7$ numbers you haven't chosen; do this in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways. All together, we have

$$ P(X=2) = \frac{\binom{12}{2} \binom{10}{3} \binom{7}{3}}{627264} = \frac{277200}{627264} \approx 0.442$$

For the sake of completeness, here are the other probabilities involving $X=n$:

$$P(X=3) = \frac{\binom{12}{3} \binom{9}{2} \binom{7}{2}}{627264} = \frac{166320}{627264} \approx 0.265$$

$$P(X=4) = \frac{\binom{12}{4} \binom{8}{1} \binom{7}{1}}{627264} = \frac{27720}{627264} \approx 0.044$$

$$P(X=5) = \frac{\binom{12}{5} \binom{7}{0} \binom{7}{0}}{627264} = \frac{792}{627264} \approx 0.001$$

We can't forget about $P(X=0)$ though! So here's that:

$$P(X=0) = \frac{\binom{12}{0} \binom{12}{5} \binom{7}{5}}{627264} = \frac{16632}{627264} \approx 0.027$$

Checking our probabilities, we see that the sum of the above answers is equal to 1 (the round-off error to 3 places after the decimal was negligible). Can you see the pattern yet? A previous answer describes it, but the probability that you will share $n$ numbers with your friend is:

$$P(X=n) = \left(\frac{1}{\binom{12}{5}\binom{12}{5}}\right){12 \choose n}{12-n\choose 5-n}{12-5\choose 5-n}$$ Hopefully this explanation will also give you insight on how to approach similar problems in the future.

Comment: If you want the probability you should divide by ${12\choose5}{12\choose5}$ at the end.

Comment: @Kaladin Thanks for noticing that! My edit reflects your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As numerator you'll get$${12 \choose n}{12-n\choose 5-n}{12-5\choose 5-n}$$
(combinations you get the same $n$ numbers)(of the remaining $12-n$ you have to pick $5-n$)(of the remaining $12-n-(5-n)=12-5$ he has to pick $5-n$ numbers)